# Tic tac toe move shows up in other slot in array then on the board. javascript

Tags: javascript

I'am creating a tik tak toe game with javascript. So right now i'am making it that you can play vs the computer. And i got it to work but right now it does fill in a field on the board, and i also have a array with the gameState to track which fields on the board are already filled in. But what it does right now is that in that array the move of the computer gets in a wrong position SOMETIMES. Not always but like 50/50 and sometimes it doesn't even showup in the array. Ill put my code for the computer down below. The fields variable is just a querySelectorAll for the fiels of the board.

```
function handleComputerMove() {
    const emptyFields = [];
    let randomField;

    if (!gameActive || !gameState.includes("")) {
        return;
    }

    fields.forEach(function(cell){
        if (cell.textContent == '') {
          emptyFields.push(cell);
        }
    });

    randomField = Math.ceil(Math.random() * emptyFields.length -1);
    emptyFields[randomField].innerHTML = currentPlayer;
    handleCellPlayed(randomField);
    handleResultValidation();
}
```

Comment: *" sometimes it doesn't even showup in the array"*: where do you modify the array? It is not reflected in the code you have shared. What have you done to debug your code? Did you put breakpoints? Did you inspect variables? ...

Comment: Hey sorry i forgot to mention what handleCellPlayed does. 

```function handleCellPlayed(i) {
    gameState[i] = currentPlayer;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code to *reproduce* the issue. Also, why do you use a non-standard way to get a random integer? The common way is `Math.floor(Math.random() * emptyFields.length)`. Remember that `Math.random()` can return 0.

Comment: made a codepen from it https://codepen.io/soudshoorn/pen/QWapGdN 

When you cant click on some fields sometimes that means that that one is marked in the array

Comment: You know you can make a runnable snippit *inside* your question. Use the toolbar `<>` button to create it.

Comment: Sorry man, kinda new to stackoverflow. Will definitely use that in the future, thanks.

Comment: That index problem you mentioned. How would you recommend me to fix this. Dont really understand what you mean

Comment: My answer addresses the index problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the index in `emptyFields` is *not* (necessarily) the index of the cell that is free.

So you should translate that back to the cell's index, which is what you could store in `emptyFields` (instead of the cell element).

Not your issue, but you should use the more common way to generate a random integer, because `Math.random()` can in theory return 0.

So:

```
fields.forEach(function(cell, i){
    if (cell.innerHTML == '') {
      emptyFields.push(i); // Store i, instead of cell
    }
});

randomField = emptyFields[Math.floor(Math.random() * emptyFields.length)];
fields[randomField].innerHTML = currentPlayer;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I understand the problem I was having now.